# Understanding "ratio" parameter in matchit()

Tags: r, match, matching

I am having trouble understanding the "ratio" parameter in the matchit() function.

According to the documentation, the `ratio = 1` parameter with `method = "nearest"` should match on a 1:1 ratios cases and controls. 
In this case, however, it seems to just mirror the distribution from the original variable:

```
library(MatchIt)
data("lalonde")

attach(lalonde)
table(treat)                                  # 429 non treated, 185 treated
prop.table(table(treat))                      # 0.699 non treated, 0.301 treated
table(age, treat); t.test(age ~ treat)        # different
table(black, treat); chisq.test(black, treat) # different
detach(lalonde)

m_exact_test <- matchit(treat~age + black, data = lalonde, method = "exact", ratio = 1)
```

Calling `m_exact_test` returns:

```
Call: 
matchit(formula = treat ~ age + black, data = lalonde, method = "exact", 
    ratio = 1)

Exact Subclasses: 34

Sample sizes:
          Control Treated
All           429     185
Matched       262     161
Unmatched     167      24
```

and the ratio 363:161 is again 0.619 to 0.381.
For completeness: switching `black` and `age` in the formula call does not change the output.

I do realize from the reply to [Exact age matched match with Matchit doesn't work.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51688246/exact-age-matched-match-with-matchit-doesnt-work) that the control:treatment ratio being tilted is part of the problem, however I do not understand why the `ratio` parameter is not solving that.

And, for completeness: why does this problem not arise in the sample call in the documentation in the matchit() function `matchit(treat ~ re74 + re75 + educ + black + hispan + age,data = lalonde, method = "nearest")`?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

The `ratio` argument is ignored for `method = "exact"`. If you want a 1:1 match (and I don't know why you would, since more exact matches is always better, all else equal), just discard some of the matched control units. Also, you've misread the output: the ratio of matched controls to treated is **262** to 161, which is not the same as the ratio of controls to treated in the original sample.

The problem doesn't arise when using `method = "nearest"` because the `ratio` argument is not ignored for that method, as described in the documentation.